# locate critical points/values and show where function is a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f(x,y,z) = (x + y + z - 1)^2$.

a. Locate the critical points and critical values of $f$.

b. For what values of $c$ is the set $f(x,y,z) = c$ a regular surface?

a. So, to locate critical points of $f$, we can say $f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$ at a critical point $p$

$f_x = 2(x + y + z - 1) = 0$

$f_y = 2(x + y + z - 1) = 0$

$f_z = 2(x + y + z - 1) = 0$

The critical points would be such that $(x_p,y_p,z_p) = (x, y, 1 - x - y)$.

Not sure how to describe critical values, plugging in would just give you $0$ again.

b.
$c \in f(U)$ is regular value of $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, iff $(f_x,f_y,f_z) = (0,0,0)$ is not in the inverse image
$f^{-1}(c) = \{(x,y,z) \in U: f(x,y,z) = c\}$.

So, we should have that c is a regular value (and thus $f(x,y,z)$ a regular surface) in the set
$f^{-1}(c) = \{(x,y,z) \in U : f(x,y,z) = c = (x + y + z - 1)^2, c \neq (x_p, y_p, z_p)\}$

Can someone provide some feedback/clarification?

Comment: The function can only be positive or zero, so its minimum value is zero, and there is no maximum.  The minimum occurs _anywhere_ on the plane $ \ x + y + z = 1 \ $ , as the derivatives show.  If that expression is typed correctly, it does seem like a strange choice for such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. the critical points are all points on the plane $x+y+z=1$
2. the critical values are the values of $f$ on the above plane which is zero since $f$ vanishes on this plane.
3. the surface is regular when $\nabla f=(f_x,f_y,f_z)\ne 0$, and hence $x+y+z\ne 1$ this implies that $f=c\ne 0$ i.e. $c$ is any positive value

Comment: i see, positive cause of the squared, forgot about that part